# Deactivate the output format temporarily in IPython

Tags: python, django

I am learning CBV of Django and intend to make a note for all the methods of `ListView`.
I am working in IPython.

```
In [31]: dir(ListView)
Out[31]:
[...
'as_view',
 'content_type',
 'context_object_name',
 'dispatch',
 'get',
 ...
 ]
```

I plan to copy it to my notebook for further reference, whereas the readable format occupies too much space.
As a solution,I pasted it to a standard python console to get a compact output:

```
[...,'as_view', 'content_type', 'context_object_name', 'dispatch', 'get'....]
```

It's not possible to write a function to get such an output in the IPython console.

How to achieve it in IPython console?

Comment: try `print(dir(ListView))` instead of `dir(ListView)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do `print(dir(ListView))`, or `print dir(ListView)` if you are using Python 2